# I don't fully understand D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN: why is it needed, what's the difference, and why does Microsoft's sample code mismatch types anyway?

Tags: winapi, direct2d

I'm reading up on Direct2D before I migrate my GDI code to it, and I'm trying to figure out how paths work. I understand most of the work involved with geometries and geometry sinks, but there's one thing I don't understand: the `D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN` type and its parameter to `BeginFigure()`.

First, why is this value even needed? Why does a geometry need to know if it's filled or hollow ahead of time? I don't know nay other drawing API which cares about whether path objects are filled or not ahead of time; you just define the endpoints of the shapes and *then* call `fill()` or `stroke()` to draw your path, so how are geometries any different?

And if this parameter is necessary, how does choosing one value over the other affect the shapes I draw in?

Finally, if I understand the usage of this enumeration correctly, you're supposed to only use filled paths with `FillGeometry()` and hollow paths with `DrawGeometry()`. However, [the hourglass example here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and cited by several method documentation pages (like the [`BeginFigure()` one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316929%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) creates a filled figure and draws it with both `DrawGeometry()` and `FillGeometry()`! Is this undefined behavior? Does it have anything to do with the blue border around the gradient in the example picture, which I don't see anywhere in the code?

Thanks.

**EDIT** Okay I think I understand what's going on with the gradient's weird outline: the gradient is also transitioning alpha values, and the fill is overlapping the stroke because the stroke is centered on the line, and the fill is drawn *after* the stroke. That still doesn't explain why I can fill and stroke with a filled geometry, or what the difference between hollow and filled geometries are...

Also I just realized that hollow geometries are documented as not having bounds. Does this mean that hollow geometries are purely an optimization for stroke-only geometries and otherwise behave identically to a filled geometry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to better understand Direct2D's geometry system, I recommend studying the WPF geometry system. WPF, XPS, Direct2D, Silverlight, and the newer "XAML" frameworks all use the same building blocks (the same "language", if you will). I found it easier to understand the declarative object-oriented API in WPF, and after that it was a breeze to work with the imperative API in Direct2D. You can think of WPF's mutable geometry system as an implementation of the "builder" pattern from Java, where the build() method is behind the scenes (hidden from you) and spits out an immutable Direct2D geometry when it comes time to render things on-screen (WPF uses something called "MIL", which IIRC/AFAICT, Direct2D was forked from. They really are the same thing!) It is also straightforward to write code that converts between the two representations, e.g. walking a WPF PathGeometry and streaming it into a Direct2D geometry sink, and you can also use [`ID2D1PathGeometry::Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371525(v=vs.85).aspx) and a custom `ID2D1GeometrySink` implementation to reconstitute a WPF PathGeometry.

(BTW this is not theoretical :) It's exactly what I do in Paint.NET 4.0+: I use a WPF-esque declarative, mutable object model that spits out immutable Direct2D geometries at render time. It works really well!)

Okay, anyway, to get directly to your specific question: `BeginFigure()` and `D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN` map directly to the [`PathFigure.IsFilled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathfigure.isfilled(v=vs.110).aspx) property in WPF. In order to get an intuitive understanding of what effect this has, you can use something like KaXAML to play around with some geometries from WPF or Silverlight samples and see what the results look like. And the documentation is definitely better for WPF and Silverlight than for Direct2D.

Another key concept is that `DrawGeometry` is basically a helper method. You can accomplish the same thing by first widening your geometry with [`ID2D1Geometry::Widen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742773(v=vs.85).aspx) and then using `FillGeometry` ("widening" seems like a misnomer to me, btw: in Photoshop or Illustrator you'd probably use a verb like "stroke"). That's not to say that either one always performs better/worse ... be sure to benchmark. I've seen it go both ways. The reason you can think of this as a helper method is dependent on the fact that the lowest level of the rasterization engine can only do one thing: fill a triangle. All other drawing "primitives" must be converted to triangle lists or strips (this is also why `ID2D1Mesh` is so fast: it bypasses all sorts of processing code!). Filling a geometry requires tessellation of its interior to a list of triangle strips which can then be filled by Direct3D. "Drawing" a geometry requires applying a stroke (width and/or style): even a simple 1-pixel wide straight line must be first converted to 2 filled triangles.

Oh, also, if you want to compute the "real" bounds of a geometry with hollow figures, use `ID2D1Geometry::GetWidenedBounds` with a strokeWidth of zero. This is a discrepancy between Direct2D and WPF that puzzles me. `Geometry.Bounds` (in WPF) is equivalent to `ID2D1Geometry::GetWidenedBounds(0.0f)`.

Comment: All right, thanks. I'll keep your suggestions in mind. First, though: am I correct in assuming that the `Widen()` (or `GetWidenedGeometry()` in WPF terms) method discards the interior of the path and treats the thickened line as the filled area? That's what I'm inferring from the WPF documentation; but I just want to make sure as it would clear up some of what you said above. (As for the "widen" terminology, you probably already know this, but [I think it's a holdover from GDI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).)

Comment: Try not to think of a path as "having" an interior. What is "has" is dependent on what you're doing with it. Consider the example of filling vs. drawing a circle (ellipse) of diameter D: filling it will do what you expect. Drawing it with a stroke of N pixels wide will be the same as if you filled a [`ID2D1GeometryGroup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316581(v=vs.85).aspx) with `D2D1_FILL_MODE_ALTERNATE` that's composed of 2 circles: one with a diameter of D+(N/2), and the other with D-(N/2). "Drawing" a geometry always has a "filling" equivalent.

Comment: On its own, a path has no area, no interior, nothing. It's just a sequence of points and info on how to join them (lines vs. beziers etc). It is just pure geometry. When you compute the area of a path, for instance, you're actually computing the area of the triangles which approximate the interior when applying the classic polygon rasterization algorithm. Flagging a figure as hollow is simply an instruction to Direct2D that it should be treated in a special way at a certain point in the rendering or tesselation pipeline.

Comment: So, it's not that the interior is discarded and the thickened line is treated as the filled area. What happens is that your geometry is stroked, and then the interior of *that* is computed.

Comment: I think Direct2D lets you specify hollow vs. filled so that you can create 1 instance of a `ID2D1PathGeometry` and then pass it to both `DrawGeometry` and `FillGeometry` so that you can get hollow areas inside that aren't surrounded by stroked paths. Like with that weird example of the smiley face that's missing an upper lip ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathfigure.isfilled(v=vs.110).aspx ). This especially simplifies content creation pipelines in XAML. You can accomplish everything without it, but it's easier with it, especially for content pipelines.

Comment: All right, thanks. I'm still doing research, this time consulting both the D2D and System.Windows.Media documentation now. I've still got a bit of confusion; perhaps I'm trying too hard to reconcile the differences between Direct2D and other graphics libraries (namely cairo and Core Graphics) instead of taking each individually; I have to eventually make swappable backends for some portable code :/ But as for this topic I think I'll be fine with the information here and some further experimentation.

Comment: Update: Okay, the smiley example finally clicked for me, I think. I kept thinking the individual parts of the smiley were separate paths, but now I realize that it's all a single path with the alternate/even-odd fill mode, and the IsFilled property is saying "don't include the smile in the filling". Thanks again!